# SUM different ranges with multiple conditions

Tags: sumifs

I have offers from many suppliers and I have to chose acceptable offers by different conditions.

In `H5` I have `"p"` next to total sum of `61.900,00` in `G5`. The problem is that I have to separate total sum in `G5` by conditions from `E1 to E4`. That means I have three different sums derived from G5:

- by condition `511001` the sum is `25.400,00`
- by condition `512500` the sum is `35.000,00`
- by condition `514000` the sum is `1.500,00`

That's my question and I would like to find the solution.

```
A   B   C           D           E       F           G           H
pcs 4   1.100,00    4.400,00    511001  1.100,00    4.400,00    
pcs 10    150,00    1.500,00    514000    150,00    1.500,00    
pcs 20  1.750,00    35.000,00   512500  1.750,00    35.000,00   
pcs 10  2.100,00    21.000,00   511001  2.100,00    21.000,00   
           SUM 1: **61.900,00**                   **61.900,00** p

                    511001:
                    512500:
                    514000:
```

Comment: What language is this?  Is this an Excel question?  Please add tags

Comment: What has the p in column h got to do with your question?

Comment: It's just an cells in excel sheet... "p" should give information that offer is acceptable and should be taken into final calculation (it's just a part of potentialy huge set of informations)

Answer (score 0):

Easiest option is to use your 'condition' labels as variables; by removing the ':' from the labels then you can just refer to the labels in the sumif.

e.g.

Change D7 to `511001`

Change E7 to `SUMIF(E1:E4,D7,G1:G4)`

Repeat for D8/E8 and D9/E9

Comment: Thanks for reply, that's just cells from excel (":" is not necessary) and I know that's easy to find a sum in those four rows, but I want to apply solution for potentialy huge set of informations.

Comment: This option works for a potentially huge set of information.